# how to compare php's callable types?

Tags: php

How do I compare two callable types to check if they are equal or the same?

```
function addCallable(callable $cb)
{
    if(/*already exists*/)
        throw new Exception("Callable was already added to the collection");
    else
        $this->collection[] = $cb;
}

function removeCallable(callable $cb)
{
    $key = array_search(/* ??? */);
    unset($this->collection[$key]);
}

$this->addCallable(array('MyClass', 'myCallbackMethod'));
try{ $this->addCallable('MyClass::myCallbackMethod'); }catch(Exception $e){}
$this->removeCallable('MyClass::myCallbackMethod');
```

thank you very much

Comment: What is "equal callables" ? They return same things? (btw, it's very vague description) Or what?

Comment: equal [$a, 'myMethod'] == [$b, 'myMethod'], same [$a, 'myMethod'] === [$a, 'myMethod']

Answer (score 8):

You could use **the third parameter** of **[is_callable](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-callable.php)** function to get the **callable name**, which is a string.

If the callable is `array('MyClass', 'myCallbackMethod')`, then the callable name will be `'MyClass::myCallbackMethod'`.

```
function addCallable(callable $cb)
{
    is_callable($cb, true, $callable_name);

    if(isset($this->collection[$callable_name])) {
        throw new Exception("Callable was already added to the collection");
    } else {
        $this->collection[$callable_name] = $cb;
    }          
}

function removeCallable(callable $cb)
{
    is_callable($cb, true, $callable_name);
    unset($this->collection[$callable_nam]); 
}
```

Comment: Nice, didn't know about the 3rd param!